# Неполное цитирование

Tags: цитата

Правильно ли здесь расставлены знаки препинания? Нужны ли многоточия?

> Пословица дальновидности «Готовь сани летом...» здесь неприемлема и
>   правильна только в своей второй части: «...а телегу – зимой».

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Да, правильно. Многоточия нужны, чтобы показать, что цитируется только часть, не все предложение.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то нелогично получается: ***Пословица дальновидности «Готовь сани летом...» здесь неприемлема*** (**!**) и правильна только в своей второй части: «...а телегу – зимой». Чтобы избежать нарушения логики, я бы написал: ***Первая часть пословицы дальновидности "Готовь сани летом, а телегу -- зимой" здесь неприемлема, верна только её вторая часть***.

Answer (score 2):

Рассказывает Дитмар Эльяшевич:

> Особый случай пунктуационного оформления при разрыве заключенных в
> кавычки слов (названия литературного произведения, промышленного
> предприятия и т. д.) находим в таком примере: ***«Пиковая...»*** ли
> это ***«...дама»?*** (реплика собеседника в ответ на утверждение, что
> представленный текст является отрывком из «Пиковой дамы»).

[§121. Авторские слова внутри прямой речи (п.1 примечание 1)](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm)

Знаки в Вашем примере на месте.